# Dúvida Função / Callback GoLang

Tags: http, golang, twitter-api

Eu preciso necessariamente tratar da response pra função ser executada? Do jeito que está ele diz que a variável "tweet" foi declarada mas não usada, mas como é uma requisição POST, eu não vejo sentido em tratar da resposta.

```
  //tokens auth
    httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)
    api := twitter.NewClient(httpClient)
    tweet, resp, err := api.Statuses.Update("tweet teste", nil)
  //fim
```

Nas documentações não têm exemplos práticos, apenas modos de uso.

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/twitter#StatusService.Update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em geral, faz sentido tratar a resposta. Mas, se não quer utilizar, use o `_`.

Isso é, considerando que tenha uma função:

```
func SuaFuncao() (string, int, error) {
return "texto", 42, nil
}
```

Essa função retorna três valores, assim como o `api.Statuses.Update`. A ordem são sempre iguais (`(string, int, error)`). Tipicamente você faria:

```
resp, code, err := SuaFuncao()
if err != nil {
return err
}
```

Porém, se você não quer usar nem o `resp` e nem o `code`, troque por `_`:

```
_, _, err := SuaFuncao()
if err != nil {
return err
}
```

Isso será suficiente para apenas obter o `err` e ignorar os outros 2 valores.

---

Isso é bem comum para utilizar em loops, por exemplo:

```
for _, v := range xxxxx {
}
```

O `_` ignora o index do `range`. Então, você pode usar isso sempre, em qualquer contexto.